# How can I solve this vertical tab problem in material UI using react.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to implement a vertical tab using material UI in react.js. For some reason the tabs not appearing. Here is the code :

Javascript:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const handleChange1 = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
```

UI:

```
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
      >
        <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    display: 'flex',
    height: 400,
  },
  tabs: {
    borderRight: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    width:100
  },
```

The final result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUT7L.png

Answer (score 0):

Firstly delete `enter code here` part, secondly css display might cause the problem. Try to change display as "block"

here's demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-lj0bu?file=/demo.js